# Faster way to do multi texture blending(HLSL, triplanar texturing and overhang mapping)

Tags: textures, directx11, hlsl, sharpdx, blending

Right now I'm doing a lot of lerping to blend my textures based on height(under water, mid ground and height ground), normal.y >= 0.0 for the under side of the terrain, fractal blend map for a marble effect and then triplanar mapping for the slopes.

It looks good and runs ok and I'm getting just the right blending effect where I need but I'm just thinking that all the lerping could be bad?

I end up with this in my terrain shader:

```
//Find the blend value for the blend zones
float IsLowGround = saturate(max(distance(min(input.WSPosition.y, 350), 350) / 300, 0));
float IsHeighGround = saturate(max(distance(min(input.WSPosition.y, 1500), 1500) / 1250, 0));

//Find the flip value
float3 flip = saturate(float3(normal.x < 0.0, normal.y >= 0.0, normal.z < 0.0));

//triplanar
float3 blend_weights = max((abs(normal) - 0.2) * 0.5f, 0.0f);
blend_weights = pow(blend_weights,2.0f);     
float total = (blend_weights.x + blend_weights.y + blend_weights.z);
blend_weights /= total;
float2 coord1 = float2(input.WSPosition.zy / 750);
float2 coord2 = float2(input.WSPosition.zx / 150);
float2 coord3 = float2(input.WSPosition.xy /700); 

//Marble blend maps
float Blend = BlendMap.Sample(colorSampler, input.WSPosition.xz / 2500).r; // flat blend
float Blend2 = BlendMap.Sample(colorSampler, input.WSPosition.zy / 6000).r;   //slope blend

//Color and Normal blending

//Slope Color With Marble
Color += lerp(ColorMap.Sample(colorSampler, coord1) * blend_weights.x, ColorMap6.Sample(colorSampler, coord1 * 3) * blend_weights.x,Blend2);
Color += lerp(ColorMap2.Sample(colorSampler, coord3) * blend_weights.z, ColorMap6.Sample(colorSampler, coord3 * 3) * blend_weights.z, Blend2);

//Slope Normal with marble
NormalM += lerp(NormalMap.Sample(colorSampler, coord1).rgb * blend_weights.x, NormalMap6.Sample(colorSampler, coord1 * 3).rgb * blend_weights.x, Blend2);
NormalM += lerp(NormalMap2.Sample(colorSampler, coord3).rgb * blend_weights.z, NormalMap6.Sample(colorSampler, coord3 * 3).rgb * blend_weights.z, Blend2);


//Height based Color Blending with marble eg. (mid -> height) -> marble
float4 GroundColor = lerp(lerp(ColorMap5.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 / 1.5) * blend_weights.y, ColorMap1.Sample(colorSampler, coord2) * blend_weights.y, IsHeighGround), ColorMap7.Sample(colorSampler, coord2) * blend_weights.y, Blend);

 //Height based Normal Blending with marble eg. (mid -> height) -> marble
float3 GroundNormal = lerp(lerp(NormalMap5.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 / 1.5).rgb * blend_weights.y, NormalMap1.Sample(colorSampler, coord2).rgb * blend_weights.y, IsHeighGround), NormalMap7.Sample(colorSampler, coord2).rgb * blend_weights.y, Blend);

 //Last Color Blending with underside flip eg. (underwater -> Ground) -> flip
Color += lerp(ColorMap4.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 / 2) * blend_weights.y, lerp(GroundColor, ColorMap3.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 * 1.2) * blend_weights.y, IsLowGround), flip.y);

 //Last Normal Blending with underside flip eg. (underwater -> Ground) -> flip   
NormalM += lerp(NormalMap4.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 / 2).rgb * blend_weights.y, lerp(GroundNormal, NormalMap3.Sample(colorSampler, coord2 * 1.2).rgb * blend_weights.y, IsLowGround), flip.y);
```

Here is what it looks like when rendered:
[image]

Comment: Lerps are pretty cheap. For an effect like this, it's texture samples that are usually the limiting factor. [Check out the section of this talk about REDengine3 where they discuss triplanar mapping performance and "blend zone tightening" to reduce the number of texture samples they use.](http://gdcvault.com/play/1020394/Landscape-Creation-and-Rendering-in)

Comment: I assumed lerp was cheap because they want u to use it rather than write it by hand. Just wasn't sure if all the lerping would add up.

The shader is still a prototype so ill move over to texturearrays very soon, sampling will still suck but I wont have to fill so many slots

Thanks for your input, checking it out now!